# replacing numbers with there respective descriptions from other table in mysql

Tags: mysql, replace

i have a table "cat_id" with fields id and category and looks like this:

```
id    category
1      23/47/2345/765
2      93/3/256/23/4700
3      23/47/443
4      76/223/5
```

and other table with name for each category. this table "description" looks like this:

```
id     name
23     abc
47     xyz
2345   aabbcc
765    xxyyzz
93     .....
```

now i want to update the table "cat_id" and replace and use these names instead of category id's

result:

```
id    category
1     abc/xyz/aabbcc/xxyyzz
2     .....
```

Comment: Consider normalizing your table first.

Comment: Using "pure" MySQL queries for this sort of task can be very complicated. Can you use a scripting language (Python, PHP, or others) to do this? They are better tools for splitting data

Answer (score 0):

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS split_count$$
CREATE FUNCTION split_count(str VARCHAR(200), delim CHAR(1)) RETURNS INT
  RETURN (LENGTH(REPLACE(str, delim, CONCAT(delim, ' '))) - LENGTH(str)) $$

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS split_replace$$
CREATE FUNCTION split_replace(str VARCHAR(200), delim CHAR(1)) RETURNS VARCHAR(200)
BEGIN
  DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE rstr VARCHAR(200) DEFAULT NULL;

  WHILE i <= split_count(str, delim)
  DO
    SELECT `name` INTO @replaced_name FROM description WHERE id = SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(str, delim, i+1), delim, -1);
    SET rstr = CONCAT_WS(delim, rstr, @replaced_name);
    SET i = i + 1;
  END WHILE;
  RETURN rstr;
END $$

DELIMITER ;

UPDATE cat_id SET category = split_replace(category, '/');
```

Comment: Try to provide a brief description of your code without posting only code to improve the quality of the answer